# Updating the expected value of an unkown card drawn from a deck of cards

Tags: probability

For simplicity, assume the deck consists of 4 sets of cards with values from 1 to 10 (40 cards in total).

Suppose we draw a random card from the deck but never look at it. Of course, its expected value is 5.5.
Now suppose we draw more cards at random, this time looking at them. Does this change the expected value of the first card? If so, in what way?

I am struggling to wrap my head around this. My intuition tells me the new information does not affect the expected value of the first card. But also it is clear that if we were to later draw 4 cards of the same value then that would affect the expected value because then we would know for sure that it is not that specific value. Any pointers appreciated!

**Edit:**

I ran 1000000 simulations and confirmed that subsequent cards do affect the expected value of the original card, yielding the same value as if the first card was actually drawn last.

Here is the code for anyone interested:

```
times = 1_000_000
sum = 0
count_all = 0 

for _ in range(times):
    cards = list(range(10)) + list(range(10)) # create the deck consisting of two sets of 0 through 9 inclusively

    # pick one at random (this is the one we "don't look at")
    first_pick_index = math.floor(random.random()*20)
    first_pick = cards[first_pick_index]
    cards = cards[:first_pick_index] + cards[first_pick_index+1:]

    # pick another card from the remaining deck
    second_pick_index = math.floor(random.random()*19)
    second_pick = cards[second_pick_index]
    cards = cards[:second_pick_index] + cards[second_pick_index+1:]

    if second_pick == 1:
        count_all += 1
        sum += first_pick

print(sum/count_all, count_all)
```

Comment: Of course.  Knowing that the some specific cards have been drawn tells you that the unseen one is from a restricted deck.  As you suggest, if you looked at all $39$ of the other cards, you'd know the value of the first one with certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example, which is simpler than your question but illustrates the same point. Assume I give you a bag with $3$ balls, some of which are red, and some of which are white. It is possible that all of them are red and all white. You do not know how many of each color there are in the bag.

Say you draw two balls from the bag and both come up white. What is the best estimation of the color of the remaining ball?

There are two alternatives. $a.$ All the balls are white; $b.$ there are two whites (the ones you drew) and one red. The best estimation is to say that all the balls are white, because if all the balls are white the probability of the event you saw (drawing two whites) is $1$; however, if two whites and one red were in the bag, the probability of the event you saw (drawing two whites) is $1/3$.

This is an example of observed data altering the expectation of other observations. In this case, the observation whose expected value we inquire is future (the drawing of the third ball). But this is incidental; the only important fact is that the event in question is unknown. In the same way in which observed data alters our expectations of an unknown future event, it may alter that of an unknown past event (the first card you drew).

**Answer to the point made in your comment:**

Your simulation is evaluating something different. It tests for the expected value of the conditional probability $P(X_3 = White \mid X_1 = X_2 = White)$. However, you set the probability that a ball is red or white to $p = 0.5$ in advance. Since the events are independent, of course the conditional probability converges to 0.5: You have set this probability yourself!

My example illustrates a totally different scenario. We assume $p$ is unknown! It could be any value in $[0, 1]$. Now assume that the first two balls were white. What is your best estimation for $p$ (this can be rephrased as what is your best estimation for the color of the last ball). The best estimation is in fact $p = 1$, since this is what makes the events you saw more likely. This simple logic is the principle behind maximum likelihood estimation, and is just one of many examples of how observed data can modify our expectancy with respect to unknown quantities.

Comment: I wasn't convinced so I wrote a Python program to simulate this: https://pastebin.com/AcVsWgqP

The result for 1000000 simulations is that the third ball is white only half the time. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I edited my answer to address your concern.

Comment: By the way, this very example of the white and red balls, as well as the principle of maximum likelihood, are treated in Mathematical Statistics by Wackerly, Chapter 9.7. Keep in mind that this is just one of many examples of observed data altering our expectancy with respect to unknown values.